# What are security risks of serving user uploaded files without Content-Disposition?

Tags: web-application, attacks, http, file-upload

Imagine a server that serves untrusted user-provided files and allows other users to download them. Under some circumstances server can be tricked to return responses to download file requests without `Content-Disposition` header (i.e. files are shown in browser's window inlined)

However, other measures of security hygiene are still in place:

- Files are served at another domain than the main site's content
- Correct `Content-Type` and `X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff` exist

What are security risks of returning responses without `Content-Disposition` header?

Answer (score 2):

Depends what filetypes are allowed to be uploaded and how the files are being handled.

- If the page is directly loaded, the file ends in .php and the webserver recognizes and executes PHP files, then you risk having the entire domain compromised.
- A smaller issue is that an html file may be a phishing page, sending any results to a server controlled by the attacker (cross-domain posting via javascript may not be possible, but you can make any cross-domain request through (visible or invisible) forms). The domain and perhaps even HTTPS certificate clearly shows that it is on your domain or a subdomain (unless you use a completely different domain), and thus the user might think that the page is trustworthy.
- And perhaps other things that don't come to mind right now.